# CSF cc_deny is not working

Tags: csf

I tried to block a country in CSF Firewall

I followed this post http://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-block-a-country-using-csf-firewall/
to block ip from China

cc_deny ="CN"

While I execute csf -r

I didn't see it block any ip block

```
CC_DENY  all opt -- in !lo out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0
```

is there any other configuration i missed?

Answer (score 0):

The country blocker is blocking all ip's from a specific country but most of the ips are in geoip database and geopip database is 3rdparty software which updates regularly but it does not contain all ips, lets say that it's 90% completed.